# touchstart event is not firing in chrome os kiosk auto-launched app

Tags: touch, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os

I've built a Chrome App and would like to run it in kiosk mode, a weird thing I came across is that touchstart event is not being fired in Kiosk mode if I set the app to auto-launch

it works ok though if I run the app in normal mode

Comment: Could you post your code? That would be helpful.

Comment: Basically, the app has just a webview element that is pointing to an html page on the server. The page is listening for touchstart event on a div, like so: document.getElementById('page_content').addEventListener('touchstart', function(){ this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';}); So, this is working in a normal mode, but it isn't in kiosk mode

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems like it starts with a minimal profile.
You need to force touch (-enabled) and enable the touch events (--touch-events).

```
chromium-browser --kiosk --incognito --enabled --touch-events http://localhost
```